# Codable default values during initialization

Tags: swift, codable

I am new to Swift and I am working on a feature flag concept for my project and I am stuck using codable for default flag values. Currently my code looks like this

```
import Foundation 

class KillSwitches: Codable {

    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKeys {
        case featureOne
        case featureTwo
        case featureThree
    }

    let featureOne: Bool = true
    let featureTwo: Bool = true
    let featureThree: Bool = false
}
```

I have internal helper classes which helps with encoding and decoding of all the values from the json file and that's why its not explicitly mentioned here. Prior to this implementation I didn't have any default values and was using struct reading everything from a remote config file which was working fine. Now I am in my next step to have default values for my features if in case the remote config file is unreachable.

I was expecting that I could initialize this class so I will get an object of the class with the default just like what I was getting when I read from my remote file.

I am not able to instantiate this class without passing init(from decoder:). I even tried doing

`KillSwitches.init(from: KillSwitches.self)` which is not working either and I get the Type does not conform to expected type Decoder.

My Json looks like this

```
{
  "featureOne" : false,
  "featureTwo" : true,
  "featureThree" : true
}
```

Any guidance / pointers to resolve this problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you conform to `Encodable`, it's as if your class has explicitly declared a `encode(to:)` method and a `init(from:)` initialiser.

By declaring an initialiser with arguments, you immediately lose the default (parameterless) initialiser that the compiler generates for you when all properties have a default value. This is why you can't do `KillSwitches()`. This is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID213):

> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or class that
>   provides default values for all of its properties **and does not provide
>   at least one initializer itself.** The default initializer simply
>   creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default
>   values.

`KillSwitches` has a `init(from:)` initialiser already, so Swift doesn't provide the default initialiser.

You just have to add the parameterless initialiser in yourself:

```
class KillSwitches: Codable {

    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case featureOne
        case featureTwo
        case featureThree
    }

    let featureOne: Bool = true
    let featureTwo: Bool = true
    let featureThree: Bool = false

    init() { }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
let defaultKillSwitches = KillSwitches()
```

if you want the default values.

Comment: How stupid am I. Thanks for pointing this out and it works flawlessly. !!!

Comment: Sweeper, It always returns the default value even though I create model again with fresh value using JSONDecoder(), can you please help with this? I would get model value initially as default but once I have fresh value then it values should be replaced and get model with new values.

Comment: @pradipsutariya your question needs way more information than you have given to be answerable, such as a [mcve] among other things. I suggest you post it as a separate question.